# What can be the verb to be used for agreement on contarcts?

Tags: word-usage

What can be the best verb to be used for the process the eventually yields  contracts?

Should I use:

- Parties should **agree** on a contract
- Parties should **find** on a contract
- Parties should **sign** a contract
- Parties should **establish** a contract
- Parties should **build** a contract
- Parties should **xxxx** a contract

Comment: In legalese, the term is *execute* (and "full execution" happens on counter-signing):

Comment: Parties should **negotiate** a contract, assuming you want the entire process.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterShor. Why didn't you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't speaking legalese, and want to refer to the entire process of deciding on a contract,

> Parties should **negotiate** a contract.

If you just want to refer to the final stage,

> Parties should **sign** a contract.